# How to do video framing?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I want to input a video and save the video frame by frame, I did it using opencv python but I want it in c++ .
as im new to c++, please help me.

this is my python code

```py
import cv2 

# Function to extract frames 
def FrameCapture(path): 

    # Path to video file 
    vidObj = cv2.VideoCapture(path) 

    # Used as counter variable 
    count = 0

    # checks whether frames were extracted 
    success = 1

    while success: 

        # vidObj object calls read 
        # function extract frames 
        success, image = vidObj.read() 

        # Saves the frames with frame-count 
        cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image) 

        count += 1

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # Calling the function
    FrameCapture(path of the video)
```

Comment: Check the tutorials and documentation of OpenCV. The functions for C++ and python are normally very similar. Thus, you should be able to use the same sunctions for C++

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is what you need. This code simply read frame and write it to a directory. 




#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int, char**)
{
    Mat src;
    // use default camera as video source
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    // check if we succeeded
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "ERROR! Unable to open camera\n";
        return -1;
    }
    // get one frame from camera to know frame size and type
    cap >> src;
    // check if we succeeded
    if (src.empty()) {
        cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
        return -1;
    }
    bool isColor = (src.type() == CV_8UC3);
    //--- INITIALIZE VIDEOWRITER
    VideoWriter writer;
    int codec = VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');  // select desired codec (must be available at runtime)
    double fps = 25.0;                          // framerate of the created video stream
    string filename = "/home/rnd/TEST/live.avi";             // name of the output video file
    writer.open(filename, codec, fps, src.size(), isColor);
    // check if we succeeded
    if (!writer.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "Could not open the output video file for write\n";
        return -1;
    }
    //--- GRAB AND WRITE LOOP
    cout << "Writing videofile: " << filename << endl
         << "Press any key to terminate" << endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        // check if we succeeded
        if (!cap.read(src)) {
            cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
            break;
        }
        // encode the frame into the videofile stream
        writer.write(src);
        // show live and wait for a key with timeout long enough to show images
        imshow("Live", src);
        if (waitKey(5) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    // the videofile will be closed and released automatically in VideoWriter destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still very new to programming, especially in OpenCV, but I think you can do it this way:

1) Have a string inside while loop that will serve to write current frame inside that string. So you will convert your current count to string and your current frame would be called "Image_1.png", "Image_2.png", etc.

```
frame_string = "Image_" + std::to_string(count + 1) + ".png";
```

2) Write the current string as an output frame, so, frame_string will be your frame name and current_frame will be currently detected frame from your video.

```
cv::imwrite(frame_string, current_frame);
```

3) Also, if you want it to be a bit cleaner, make a folder inside your directory (example: Images) and store images inside that directory like:

```
frame_string = "Images/Image_" + std::to_string(count + 1) + ".png";
```

So, code might look like this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {

  cv::VideoCapture cap("RandomVideo.mp4");
  cv::Mat frame;
  std::string frame_string;
  int count = 0;

  while (true) {
      cap.read(frame);

      // When frame is empty, break the while loop
      if (frame.empty())
        break;

      // Display frame
      cv::imshow("Original", frame);

      // Write frame
      frame_string = "Image_" + std::to_string(count + 1) + ".png";
      cv::imwrite(frame_string, frame);

      // Show current frame in console
      std::cout << "Current frame: " << count << std::endl;

      count++;
      cv::waitKey(1);   // Short delay
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.